# HaProxy Run script in case of health check failure

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to perform an action such as the execution of a script in case a health check failure occurs and a backup server is activated from the configuration of the HaProxy; If HaProxy does not support this feature, is there some other way to monitor such behavior to keep track of the active machine automatically ;